# "Argument of type 'IArguments' is not assignable" error for arguments?

Tags: typescript

I'm doing something hacky but sadly necessary. I need to surpress certain console errors that are in fact harmless.

```
export const removeConsoleErrors = () => {
  const cloneConsoleError = console.error;

  const suppressedWarnings = [
    'Warning: React does not recognize the `%s` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `%s` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.%s',
    'Warning: Using the "className" prop on <View> is deprecated.', `View`.',
  ];

  console.error = function filterWarnings(msg: string) {
    if (!suppressedWarnings.some((entry) => msg.includes(entry))) {
      cloneConsoleError.apply(console, arguments);
    }
  };
};
```

This works but I'm getting a TypeScript error for `arguments:

> Argument of type 'IArguments' is not assignable to parameter of type '[any?, ...any[]]'.  TS2345

I can fix the error with this, but it seems quite verbose. Is there a shorter way of writting it?

```
Const argumentsTyped: any = arguments;
cloneConsoleError.apply (console, argumentsTyped);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use the arguments magic variable anymore. Your code will work fine with the spread syntax:

```
export const removeConsoleErrors = () => {
  const cloneConsoleError = console.error;

  const suppressedWarnings = [
    'Warning: React does not recognize the `%s` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `%s` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.%s',
    'Warning: Using the "className" prop on <View> is deprecated.', `View`
  ];

  console.error = function filterWarnings(...args) {
    const [msg] = args;
    if (!suppressedWarnings.some((entry) => msg.includes(entry))) {
      cloneConsoleError(...args);
    }
  };
};
```